# Do the touch events touchleave and touchenter exist?

Tags: javascript, html, multi-touch

I've tried a couple different devices and I have never been able to see a `touchleave` or `touchenter` event. I've tried:

- chrome, enabling touch event emulation
- chrome and firefox using [phantom limb](http://www.vodori.com/blog/phantom-limb.html)
- Android galaxy s2 via [cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/)

So what gives? Why does mozilla list these things in [their reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent)? While we're on the subject, what kinds of things trigger `touchcancel`? I've never seen that event either.

Comment: _This should probably be its own thread_, but I've noticed `touchcancel` fires when you're touching the device and the orientation (i.e: `portrait` vs `landscape`) changes. I'm sure there are other instances, but this is why you see a lot of examples that have a `touchend` handler also bound to `touchcancel` event.

Answer (score 1):

I think they exist but they don't do anything.

Comment: That means, they are useless.

Comment: Isn't that the same thing as not existing?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried touchleave and touchenter, but both do nothing. No callback will come to there methods. I think Developers have defined these methods but forgot to implement them..